# Google collab does not find Python package

Tags: python, scikit-learn, theano, google-colaboratory

I want to use `sklearn_theano` package in Google colab.

However, I simply do that :

```
import sklearn_theano
```

and get

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn_theano'

How to make the library available ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example notebook demonstrating the install:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gYny47qg3I3iiI-i5oMKuu4ZSsIzUiIJ

It mirrors the [published installation instructions](http://sklearn-theano.github.io/install.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
!pip install -q library
```

where library is what you want to install.

Comment: Google colab allows 3rd-party installation? Interesting indeed, if that is the case.

Comment: i got this from their own documentation so I suppose yes, I think you can run google collab locally so definitely

Comment: Would be epic if we in the future could run code here on SO using google-colab or other engine, specifying setup.

Comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sklearn_theano (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for sklearn_theano